# Click on button in Android WebView programmatically

Tags: javascript, android, forms, button, submit

I am trying to fill in a few fields(Working) then click the login button(Not Working) I have tried:

```
document.getElementById('loginButton').click();"
```

and

```
document.forms['form'].submit();
```

The button name and form name are correct, what am I doing wrong?

```
webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {  
             @Override  
             public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url)  
             {  
                 webview.loadUrl("javascript:(function() { " +  
                      "document.getElementById('coCode').value = 'CompanyCode';" +
                      "document.getElementById('loginName').value = 'LoginName';" +
                      "document.getElementById('password').value = 'Password';" +
                      //"document.forms['form'].submit();" + //Doesn't Work
                      //"document.getElementById('loginButton').click();" + //Doesn't Work
                    "})()");
             }  
         });
```

Comment: `document.forms["form"].submit();` should work, have you checked that it (the javascript function) is happy in a standalone browser?

Comment: When I use document.forms["form"].submit(); the page just reloads. Maybe this will help <a id="loginButton" class="buttonbarbutton" name="loginButton" onclick="return confirmSubmit();" href='javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions("loginButton", "", true, "", "", false, true))'>Login</a>

Comment: might make more sense if we can see the HTML as well. I don't have a tablet with me to test at the moment, but can have a look tomorrow if there's an HTML sample to complete the picture (not sure what I'm missing at the moment!)

Comment: I tried webview.loadUrl("javascript:confirmSubmit()"); and the "Login" button text changed to "Logging In..." but then nothing else happens. Any thoughts?

Comment: Offbeatmammal, Thank you for trying to help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out, the following worked for me:

```
webview.loadUrl("javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(
  new WebForm_PostBackOptions('loginButton', '', true, '', '', false, true))");
```